How to configure access to `olcPPolicyDefault`?
I'm writing a utility (in Perl) that needs access to attribute olcPPolicyDefault that defines the DN of the default password policy in OpenLDAP.
As the utility should not use the Admin or cn=config account to bind to the OpenLDAP server (2.4.41 of SLES12, BTW), I defined a separate account uid=PP-Checker,... for access.
As I did not want to code the exact context (olcOverlay={2}ppolicy,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config) into the ACL, I had tried a filter:
...
olcAccess: {2}to filter=(&(objectClass=olcPPolicyConfig)(olcPPolicyDefault=*))
 attrs=olcPPolicyDefault by dn.exact="uid=PP-Checker,..." read by * break

However that did not allow access.
So I tried to add access to the parent context like this:
...
olcAccess: {1}to dn.subtree="cn=config" by dn.exact="uid=PP-Checker,..." search by * break
olcAccess: {2}to filter=(&(objectClass=olcPPolicyConfig)(olcPPolicyDefault=*))
 attrs=olcPPolicyDefault by dn.exact="uid=PP-Checker,..." read by * break

So the obvious questons are:

Is the ACL correct, and if not: How to do it correctly?
If the ACL is correct, is it defined in the correct context (olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config)

